# Using JSRT, how do you load a module and then use it?

Tags: javascript, chakracore

Using the [JavaScript Runtime](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/wiki/JavaScript-Runtime-%28JSRT%29-Reference) (JSRT), what functions would you call to load a JavaScript module and then call functions on it. For example, how would I load the file `C:\Users\camer\ts\TsAst\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js` and then access `ts.version` to return `2.4.2`?

Answer (score 2):

There's a [great example in the Chakra-Samples repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/Chakra-Samples/blob/master/ChakraCore%20Samples/JSRT%20Hosting%20Samples/C%2B%2B/ChakraCoreHost/ChakraCoreHost.cpp) for both C++ and C#.
If you're embedding on Linux, *BSD, or MacOS, you can modify the build script for above sample in line with the [Hello World example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Chakra-Samples/blob/master/ChakraCore%20Samples/Hello%20World/Linux_OSX_Shared/sample.cpp) in the same repository.

For a real-world example, [check out how React Native Windows embeds ChakraCore](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/blob/master/ReactWindows/ReactNative.Shared/Chakra/Executor/ChakraJavaScriptExecutor.cs#L140) by loading React Native JavaScript bundles using the same APIs as the samples. If you want to get fancy and do bytecode bundles to speed up app launch and time-to-interaction, React Native Windows' implementation can be used as a reference for that advanced use case as well.